# Rails for Zombies Level 3, Challenge 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a novice in both Ruby and Rails, and decided to take basic lessons through Rails for Zombies by Code School. The problem is I cannot get passed [level 3, exercise 5](http://railsforzombies.org/levels/3/challenges/5). Can someone please help me? This is getting very frustrating, since I do not understand how to link to the EDIT page, as the challenge states...

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be looking for something like:

```
 <%= link_to "Edit", edit_zombie_path(zombie) %>
```

Replace 'zombie' with the resource you're working on if needed.

Comment: Ah! There is a tick on the left of each answer. Just click it

Comment: You should not post an answer, just click the tick next to mine.

Comment: Is there any other alternate syntax to write the path? Something like: zombie.edit. @apneadiving

Comment: @AndreaM16 no, model isnt aware of view and its perfect this way. You could create a presenter t achieve this goal

Answer (score 4):

The answer that questioner is looking for

```
<%= link_to zombie.name, edit_zombie_path(zombie) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Original Hint #1

> You need to link to the zombie's edit page using
>   edit_zombie_path(zombie).

## Original Hint #2

A possible correct answer is:

```
<ul>
  <% zombies.each do |zombie| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to zombie.name, edit_zombie_path(zombie) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```